# In Haskell, is it correct measuring performance using a timestamp obtained at the beginning and in the end of a function execution?

Tags: performance, haskell

I want to measure the performance of a Haskell function. This function is executed concurrently.

Is it correct to measure its performance using timestamps that `getCurrentTime` function returns? Does lazyness affects the measuring?

I want to save these times on a log. I have looked some logging libraries, but the time they return is not as precise as the timestamp that `getCurrentTime` returns. I use [XES](http://www.xes-standard.org/) format on my log.

The code i use is something like this: (i did not compile it)

```
import Data.Time.Clock    
measuredFunction:: Int -> IO (Int,UTCTime,UTCTime)
measuredFunction x = do
    time' <- getCurrentTime
    --performs some IO action that returns x'
    time'' <- getCurrentTime
    return (x',time',time'')

runTest :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
runTest init end = do
  when (init <= end) (do 
                        forkIO (do 
                                   (x',time',time'') <- measuredFunction 1
                                   -- saves time' and time '' in a log 
                                )
                        runTest (init+1) end  )
```

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the function.  Some values have all their information immediately, whereas others can have expensive stuff going on "beyond the top layer". Here's a contrived example:

```
example :: (Int, Int)
example = (1+1, head [ x | x <- [1..], x == 10^6 ])
```

If you load this up in ghci, you will see `(2,` printed, and then after some delay, the remainder of the value `1000000)` is printed.  If you get a value like this, then the function will "return" "before" the expensive sub-value has been computed.  But you can use [`deepseq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq) to ensure that a value is computed all the way and doesn't have any sub-computations left.

Benchmarking is subtle, and there are a lot of ways to do it wrong (especially in Haskell).  Fortunately we have a very good benchmarking library called [`criterion`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) 
 *([tutorial](http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/tutorial.html))* which I definitely recommend you use if you are trying to get reliable results.

Comment: Your answer helped me, but i think that i can not use `criterion` because the function i want to measure is a function that is a sub-sub-routine. The previous functions must be called before the one i want to measure. I can not call the function directelly as `fib` is called on `criterion` tutorial.

Comment: @andregps The criterion library includes facilities for [setting up an environment before your function call](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-1.4.1.0/docs/Criterion.html#v:env).